# Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated. C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\colinmollenhour\cache-backend-file\File.php on line 81

Tags: php, xampp, magento2

I'm getting this as an error after installing magento via bitnami xammp.

> Deprecated: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls in C:\xampp\apps\magento\htdocs\vendor\colinmollenhour\cache-backend-file\File.php on line 81
>   There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>   Error log record number: 1638419606

What should I do now?

Comment: The function `each()` was deprecated in PHP 7.2. Are you using the latest version of Magento? Is your Magento version support your PHP version? Is it a plugin? Does that plugin support your PHP version? Is there a newer version of that plugin? If you really can't affect any of that, then you could change the error reporting level: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php  (however, that's not as much a "solution" as it is a workaround).

Comment: Yes. I'm using magento 2.2. And my version is PHP/7.2.1 and it is no where documented on the magento 2 system requirement,its just says that it support 7.1.x.

Comment: A quick google would have given you the answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205087/magento-2-2-is-not-working-in-php-7-2-0 (that's just one of many posts about issues with Magento 2.2 with PHP 7.2).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because you use php 7.2 which Magento doesn't support currently, even in 2.3 pre-release. You can downgrade to php 7.1.X and use Magento 2.2.X or downgrade to php 7.0.7.X and use Magento  2.1.X.

More information about Magento versions and its php support [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).

Comment: And how exactly I should downgrade to 7.1.x .I would be grateful if you can elaborate on that. I'm new to web development.

Comment: @tahadalvi It depends on what system you are using. Is it windows ? Unix ? macOS ? and what kind of unix if you use it? (arch, debian..)

Comment: It's windows 7 32 bits.

Comment: @tahadalvi then you can simply dowload the php 7.1 installer, and choose your current php 7.2 location to install it / extract it. Or just uninstall / delete 7.2 before.

Comment: @tahadalvi my pleasure ! be sure to check if somebody already answered your question in stackoverflow or an other forum using google next time

Comment: Sure... I will.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this error by changing my php version in wamp down from 7.2 to 7.1 and the error went away and now i'm able to install.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
while (list($name, $value) = each($options)) {
   $this->setOption($name, $value);
}
```

To

```
foreach ($options as $name => $value){
   $this->setOption($name, $value);
}
```

Reference in: https://community.magento.com/t5/Installing-Magento-2-x/Deprecated-The-each-function-is-deprecated/td-p/80126

Comment: Edit your answer and add the reference link to the answer. Don't leave it in the comment.